# Custom aggregation function using 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table

```
event_name | score | date      | flag | 
event_1    | 123   | 12APR2018 |  0   |
event_1    | 34    | 05JUN2019 |  0   |
event_1    | 198   | 08APR2020 |  0   |
event_2    | 3     | 14SEP2019 |  0   |
event_2    | 34    | 22DEC2019 |  1   |
event_2    | 90    | 17FEB2020 |  0   | 
event_3    | 772   | 19MAR2021 |  1   |
```

And I want to obtain

```
event_name | sum_score | date_flag_1 | 
event_1    | 355       |             | 
event_2    | 127       | 22DEC2019   | 
event_3    | 772       | 19MAR2021   |
```

where `sum_score` is the sum of column score for the corresponding event and `date_flag_1` is the first date when `flag` = 1 for the corresponding event. If `flag` = 0 for all the rows of the current event, `date_flag_1` should be missing

I suppose that the code should look something like

```
df_agg = df.groupby('event_name').agg({'score': 'sum', ['date', 'flag']: my_custom_function})
df_agg.columns = ['event_name', 'sum_score', 'date_flag_1']
```

However, I am not sure how should I implement `my_custom_function`, which would be a custom aggregation function that uses two columns instead of one (like other aggregation function). Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate twice and `concat` the results. The second aggregation you can subset then use the builtin GroupBy.first

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df.groupby('event_name')['score'].sum(),
           df[df.flag.eq(1)].groupby('event_name')['date'].first().rename('date_flag_1')], 
          axis=1)

#            score date_flag_1
#event_name                   
#event_1       355         NaN
#event_2       127   22DEC2019
#event_3       772   19MAR2021
```

---

For illustration, this *can* be done with a single `agg` call; however it will be very slow because this requires a `lambda x:` which will be calcualted as a slow loop over the groups (as opposed to vectorized/cythonized built-in GroupBy operations).

Because `.agg` only acts on a single Series the hacky work-around is to create a function that accepts both the Series and the DataFrame. You use the Series index to subset the DataFrame (you must have a non-duplicated index for this to work properly) allowing you to then do aggregations that can use multiple columns. This is both overly complicated and slow so I wouldn't do it.

```
def get_first_date(s, df):
    # rows within group where `s==1`
    res = df.loc[s[s.eq(1)].index, 'date'].dropna()

    if not res.empty:
        return res.iloc[0]
    else:
        return np.NaN

df.groupby('event_name').agg({'score': 'sum', 
                              'flag': lambda x: get_first_date(x, df)})

#            score       flag
#event_name                  
#event_1       355        NaN
#event_2       127  22DEC2019
#event_3       772  19MAR2021
```

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it also possible to do this process with a single aggregating function (wihtout concatenation)?

Comment: @pentavol It _can_ be done, but it's very hacky and complicated. `agg` really only works column by column, so you'd want to use `.apply`, but `.apply` doesn't play well with multiple aggregations. The other issue is that `.apply(my_func)` will be slow so even though the above might look bad because of two separate groupby calls, it will be fast because the built-in methods are optimized

Comment: @ALollz - thanks for the explanations. I didn't even know `apply` was slow, I only knew `iterrows` is very slow. Also, I will accept you answer in 4 minutes, currently I am not allowed to do it

Comment: @pentavol well not all apply calls are equal. I think stuff like `df.groupby('event_name')['score'].apply(sum)` will default to use the very fast built-in implementation of `DataFrame.GroupBy.Sum`. The real problem is `df.apply(lambda x: ...` or `df.apply(my_custom_func)` because those are calculated as slow loops over the groups. Might not be bad if you have a few hundred groups but with very big data it can be a big burden